# Moving Images In Swift

Tags: animation, math, swift

I want to move an image from x,y to x,y and animate the move.  I know how to do animate the move in Swift by changing the x/y cooridnates over a period of time.  My question is how do I get the straight line distance between the two points and how do I determine how much to adjust the x and y to get the image to move in a straight line?  Or is there something in Swift that I can just give it starting and ending coordinates and it will do the move for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [Ray Wenderlich Tutorial on UIView Animations](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76200/basic-uiview-animation-swift-tutorial).